# Axios request interceptor not working on browser refresh

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios interceptor in my react app to pass the token for each request.
I initially call the setupAxiosInterceptors method after I login (See code below). This works perfectly fine until I refresh the browser.

```
    const registerSucessfulLoginForJwt = (username, token) => {
          sessionStorage.setItem(USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username)
          setupAxiosInterceptors(createJwtAuth(token))    //Calling the axios interceptor at the time of login
    }
```

See below the setupAxiosInterceptors method

```
const setupAxiosInterceptors = (token) => {
   Axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
     if(isUserLoggedIn()) {
        config.headers.authorization = token
        sessionStorage.setItem('authorization', token)
     }
    return config
  })
 }
```

Any thought on how to fix this so it works at all time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem. I create an ApiSetup.js file where I create a custom axios instance which could use for all requests.

```
    const request = axios.create({
        baseURL: API_PATH_BASE
    })

    request.interceptors.request.use(config => {
        const currentUser = AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUser() //You can get the user directly from the cookie or session storage...
        if(currentUser.userName) {
            config.headers.Authorization = currentUser.userToken
        }
    return config
    }, err => {
       console.log(err)
    return Promise.reject(err)
    })

    export default request
```